# How to express that one equation (or inequality) is equal to another equation (or inequality)?

Tags: inequality, logic, notation

How do we symbolically express that $a+b=c$ is equal to $a+d=n$? Do we put an equals sign between them, or else?

Comment: Maybe, the iff-symbol is suitable.

Comment: $a+b-c=a+d-n=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 equations to be equal?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, concept of one equation being equal to another is what matters, not the values of the variables in my example (I should've indicated this earlier).

Comment: @Jakobian, one equation is equal to another equation (although they are expressed differently)?

Comment: Are these the same equations you want to say are 'equal'? What is the 'concept' of two equations being equal?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, $5+7=12$ is equal to $5+(5+2)=|-12|$.

Comment: So c = n is what you mean by two equations being equal?

Comment: @Paul, but I still need to express both equations next to each other for clarity and indication of some things (although mathematically we can write $c=n$).

Comment: It's all a bit vague though. EQUAL is a very strong statement, it's not "a bit like" or "has something to do with" and so on, it is literally equal.

Answer (score 2):

Equality as a (binary) relation only makes sense for terms, ie, numbers, variables, functions applied to those, etc.

Equations are phrases/statements, composed of relations among terms, logical operations, quantifiers, etc., and as such we attribute truth-values to them; it wouldn't really make much sense to say they are equal.

What you're probably interested is in saying they are equivalent: one is true precisely when the other is true, the same for falsity.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Distinction_from_%22if%22_and_%22only_if%22